# JS Event listener not being Invoked after using insertafter

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have two section where the second section is inserted into a div of the first section. This is done so the appropriate section is displayed side by side when any of the item in the first section is clicked.

However the issue that I am seeing is hapenning with the radio change event. The radio change event is not triggering consistently or being called if i use   **$('.checking-account-options').insertAfter('.offering-container');** (updating the DOM)

I made sure that the radio button change event is called after the DOM is updated but still having issues with firing the radio button event handler. What could be the issue here?

```js
let bankOfferingClick = document.querySelectorAll('#banks .account-offering');
if (bankOfferingClick.length)
  bankOfferingClick.forEach(button => button.addEventListener('click', updateDOM));

let radiobuttons = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="radio"]');
radiobuttons.forEach(radiobutton => {
  radiobutton.addEventListener('change', updatecheckbox);
});

function updateDOM(event) {
  $('.checking-account-options').insertAfter('.offering-container');
}

function insertAfter(referenceNode, newNode) {
  referenceNode.parentNode.insertBefore(newNode, referenceNode.nextSibling);
}

function updatecheckbox(event) {
  const target = event.target;

  if (target.type === "radio")
    for (const radio of radiobuttons) {

      if (radio.checked)
        target.previousElementSibling?.classList.add('checked');
      else
        target.previousElementSibling?.classList.remove('checked');
    }


}
```

```css
input [type="radio"] {
  display: none;
}

.radio {
  width: 1.25rem;
  height: 1.25rem;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  border-radius: 100vmax;
  margin-right: 0.5rem;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: white;
}

.radio-label {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.radiocontainer {
  padding-bottom: 1rem;
}

.radiocontainer label.radio-label.checked .radio::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 0.75rem;
  height: 0.75rem;
  background-color: black;
  border-radius: 100vmax;
}

.hide {
  display: none;
}

ul li {
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  margin-top: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body id="banks">
  <section class="bank-offering-container">
    <div style="display:flex">
      <div class="offering-container">
        <ul style="list-style: none;">
          <li class="checkingsaccount">
            <span class="account-offering">
              Checkings Account
            </span>
          </li>
          <li class="savingsaccount">
            <span class="account-offering">
             Savings Account
            </span>
          </li>
          <li class="investments">
            <span class="account-offering">
              Investments
            </span>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>

  <section class="checking-account-options">
    <div>
      <div class="radiocontainer">

        <label for="2" class="radio-label">
      <span class="radio"></span>
      Used for day to day purposes
                                           
     </label>
        <input type="radio" class="hide" id="2">
      </div>
      <div class="radiocontainer">

        <label for="3" class="radio-label">
      <span class="radio"></span>
     Used to pay off student loans
                                           
     </label>
        <input type="radio" class="hide" id="3">
      </div>

      <div class="radiocontainer">

        <label for="4" class="radio-label">
      <span class="radio"></span>
    Used to pay off mortagage 
                                           
     </label>
        <input type="radio" class="hide" id="4">
      </div>
      <div class="radiocontainer">

        <label for="5" class="radio-label">
      <span class="radio"></span>
      Used to pay off auto loan
                                           
     </label>
        <input type="radio" class="hide" id="5">
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>

</body>
```

```
<body id="banks">
  <section class="bank-offering-container">
  <div style="display:flex">
    <div class="offering-container">
      <ul style="list-style: none;">
        <li class="checkingsaccount">
          <span class="account-offering">
          Checkings Account
        </span>
        </li>
        <li class="savingsaccount">
          <span class="account-offering">
         Savings Account
        </span>
        </li>
        <li class="investments">
          <span class="account-offering">
          Investments
        </span>
        </li>
      </ul>
         </div>
        </div>
  </section>
 
<section class="checking-account-options">
  <div>
  <div class="radiocontainer">
 
 <label for ="2" class="radio-label">
  <span class="radio"></span>
  Used for day to day purposes
                                       
 </label>
 <input type="radio" class="hide" id="2">
</div>
<div class="radiocontainer">

 <label for ="3" class="radio-label">
  <span class="radio"></span>
 Used to pay off student loans
                                       
 </label>
 <input type="radio" class="hide"  id="3">
</div>

<div class="radiocontainer">

 <label for ="4" class="radio-label">
  <span class="radio"></span>
Used to pay off mortagage 
                                       
 </label>
 <input type="radio" class="hide"  id="4">
</div>
<div class="radiocontainer">
 
 <label for ="5" class="radio-label">
  <span class="radio"></span>
  Used to pay off auto loan
                                       
 </label>
 <input type="radio" class="hide" id="5">
</div>
</div>
</section>

</body>
```

Comment: I don't see any difference in the way the radio buttons work before and after they're moved with `insertAfter()`.

Comment: For some reason it is in-consistent for me and the classlist in function "updatecheckbox" does not get applied. The style in the classlist gets removed once its outside the function scope.

Comment: Radio buttons should have a `name` attribute, since that's how they're grouped. Or use checkbox instead of radio.